Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref in mvn release - Azure Pipeline
I get the following error output while running the Maven release plugin prepare step i.e. mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform .
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project TEST_C: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project TEST_C: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)

Updates:
After adding fetchDepth:0
I am getting another error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project measures_connect: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Author identity unknown
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
[ERROR]   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] to set your account's default identity.
[ERROR] Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'athulya_azpcontainer@3a075dbc4a82.(none)')
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project measures_connect: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-commit command failed.
Command output:
Author identity unknown

I tried to add git identity but getting the below error for the commands
      git config --global user.email $(build.RequestedForEmail)
      git config --global user.name $(build.RequestedFor)
      git pull origin $(Build.SourceBranch)

error: could not lock config file /home/jenkins/.gitconfig: Permission denied error: could not lock config file /home/jenkins/.gitconfig: Permission denied

Updates on 11/07/2024:
Please find the script:
parameters:
- name: 'skipRelease'
  type: boolean
  default: false

stages:
  - stage: ValidateGitCheckin
    jobs:
      - job: Validate
        steps:
          - script: |
              git config --add safe.directory $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
              
              if [ "${{ parameters.skipRelease }}" = "true" ]; then
                echo "SKIP_RELEASE: Inherit parameter"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipRelease;isoutput=true]true"
              fi
            displayName: "Validate git checkin"

  - stage: SetupMaven
    jobs:
      - job: DownloadMaven
        steps:
          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1 
            name: settingsxml
            inputs:
              secureFile: "settings.xml"
          - script: |
              mkdir -p $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.m2
              cp $(settingsxml.secureFilePath) $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.m2/settings.xml
            displayName: "Setup Maven settings.xml"
            
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              path: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.m2
              artifact: m2
            displayName: "Download and store Maven settings.xml to artifact"


  - stage: Release
    jobs:
      - job: ReleaseJob
        container: dockerContainer
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 0
            persistCredentials: true
          - script: |

              git config --local user.email "$(build.RequestedForEmail)"
              git config --local user.name "$(build.RequestedFor)"
              git status
              if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
                echo "There are uncommitted changes"
                exit 1
              fi
            displayName: 'Added git identity'
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              artifact: m2
              path: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.m2
          - task: Maven@3
            displayName: 'Release'
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pom.xml'
              options: '-B -X -s $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.m2/settings.xml'    
              goals: 'release:clean release:prepare release:perform'

Updated the git identity script as below:
git config --local user.email "$emailId"
git config --local user.name "$(build.RequestedFor)"
git checkout feature/$(Build.SourceBranchName)


I have added the fetchDepth:0, after adding it i am facing another error:

Can you share some error details? As far as I know, the original issue is that the SCM Command is detecting the ref HEAD on current Branch. When we set fetchDepth:0 to checkout entire branch, the original issue should be resolved.

Please refer to the update in my answer. You need to run git config --global to config the username and email to solve this issue. And you need to set persistCredentials: true to set the   git credential.

And you can check if the .git folder in the repo contains the .git/config.lock file. If yes, you can remove it.

@KevinLu-MSFT i am still getting the error even after i have removed the config file and added mentioned comments.
error: could not lock config file /home/jenkins/.gitconfig: Permission denied

@Dev001 What kind of agent are you using? Self-hosted agent or Microsoft-hosted agent? If possible you can try to use Microsoft-hosted agent to run the Pipeline to confirm if it can work.

If you are using self-hosted agent, you can manually log in the local machine where the agent located and run the `git config --global user.name  command. Then you can skip the git config step in Azure Pipelines.

@KevinLu-MSFT Tried in Microsoft-hosted agent, getting the same error - Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

Have you set  fetchdepth:0 in the checkout step?

yes, all these
- checkout: self
fetchDepth: 0
persistCredentials: true

Can you share the pipeline definition with us?

Can you try to add ‘git checkout branch name’ before the maven task and check the result?

I have added git checkout $(Build.SourceBranch)  at the bottom of 'Added git identity', got the error
error: pathspec 'refs/heads/feature/23972-Pipeline-To-Release' did not match any file(s) known to git

Please try to run the command: git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName) if you need to use variable.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have checked the latest error. Please try to run the command: git checkout feature/$(Build.SourceBranchName)

@Dev001 I missed the comment in the chat room before. I have checked the permission issue now. When you use pipeline to create the branch, it will use service account to do the action. You need to grant the Contribute permission to the following two service accounts: ProjectName Build Service(OrganizationName) and Project Collection Build Service(OrganizationName). Feel free to let me know if it can work.

@KevinLu-MSFT Thank you, it got worked, but how can i generalize the git identity script to all type of branches like bugfix/feature/enhancement.
currently the branch is specified in the script

@Dev001 there is no out-of-box variable can directly get the expected name. To meet your requirement, you can use the  replace expression  to create a custom variable with the expected branch name. Refer to my update 2 in my answer. Feel free to let me know if it can work.

@KevinLu-MSFT Thank you very much, update 2 got worked :)

@KevinLu-MSFT
Now I am facing an error like below when in run mvn release prepare "This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-commit.
"


failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

From the error message, it seems that Pipeline does not checkout the entire branch.
By default, the Shallow fetch of the pipeline repo is 1 by default.
In this case, the ref will target to a single commit.
For example:

You can try to set the fetchDepth to 0 in YAML Pipeline.
For example:
YAML Pipeline
steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0

Or you can navigate to YAML Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources -> Shallow fetch.  You can unselect the option.


Classic Pipeline:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Shallow fetch
Update:

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address

To solve this issue, you need to add the following script before the maven command:
   git config --global user.email "youremail"
   git config --global user.name "yourname"

And you can set persistCredentials: true in the checkout step to make sure that the git credential is correct.
YAML sample:
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "youremail"
   git config --global user.name "yourname"
   mvn release:prepare

Update2:

how can i generalize the git identity script to all type of branches like bugfix/feature/enhancement.

There is no out-of-box variable can directly get the branch name with the format: prefix/branchname.
To meet your requirement, you need to custom a variable based on the Build.SourceBranch varaible.
Here is an example:
variables:
  branchname: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
   
steps:

- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
  persistCredentials: true
- powershell: |
     git config --local user.email "$emailId"
     git config --local user.name "$(build.RequestedFor)"
     git checkout $(branchname)

